# Is the number of sub-boolean algebra of a set with size n , Bell(n)?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra, bell-numbers

In boolean algebra (P(S),+,.,’) we must have S as 1 and {} as 0 in every possible sub-boolean algebra to hold id elements.
We must have S-x for every subset x⊆S to hold complements.
It seems like counting every possible partitions in S which is Bell(|S|) if i was not wrong.
For example the number of possible sub-boolean algebra of ⟨p({a,b,c,d}),∪,∩⟩ is Bell(4)=15 , is it right ?
If it is how we can define a bijection between every n class partitions to boolean algebra with size n ?